# What is the problem with \node[red]{X}; in RTL context (xelatex)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, right-to-left, bidi

This example on tikz node if I use `\node[red]{x};` in math mode (RTL context) the node appears faraway unlike `\node[color=red]{x};`, I thought the two were equivalent

In pgfmanual (Page 173) we can find that

> What happens is that every option that TikZ does not know, like
> red!20, gets a “second chance” as a color name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}

\huge

\setRTL 

Text start here

$$ A \tikz\node[red]{X}; B$$

\bigskip

$$ A \tikz\node[color=red]{X}; B$$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem do not appears if we use just  `\beginR` provided to change text direction and used intensively in `bidi` package

**Example without bidi**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\TeXXeTstate=1

\begin{document}

\huge

\everypar{\beginR}

Text start here

$$ A \tikz\node[red]{X}; B$$

\bigskip

$$ A \tikz\node[color=red]{X}; B$$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this very particular case `\color` is called, which is known for not working well in the RTL mode. Neutralize it by `\def\color#1{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A step by step breakdown:

- `red` is not a predefined Ti*k*Z key.
- `/tikz/.unknown/.code` is called.
  (`tikz.code.tex` line 1651)
  This is the routine that checks if the passed key is
  (a) a PGF key,  (b) a color, (c) an arrow, or (d) a shape
- `red` is a color;
  `\tikz@addoption{\tikz@compat@color@set{red}}` is fired.
- `\tikz@compat@color@set`
  (`tikz.code.tex` line 1687)
  calls `\pgfutil@color`.
- `\pgfutil@color`
  (`pgfutil-latex.def` line 30)
  calls `\color`.
- Boom.